# How does Java's Vector add a primitive array?

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I'm using Java 1.3, which means that it does not have autoboxing of primitives. This means that the following code:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
byte b = (byte) 4;

v.addElement(b);
```

Does not compile, with the compiler error:

```
The method addElement(Object) in the type Vector is not applicable for the arguments (byte)
```

All primitives must be wrapped, like so:

```
v.addElement(new Byte(b));
```

With that being said, I noticed that this code compiles and runs just fine:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
byte[] b = new byte[]{1, 2};

v.addElement(b);
```

How is that possible? My version of java doesn't even have collections, and [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) says that the method is not overloaded, it only takes Objects.

Is it the case that all arrays, even arrays of primitives, actually extend Object?

Comment: Even in Java 1.3, using a List was preferred to using a Vector unless you have to. Storing `Byte`s in a collection is very inefficient using around 20 bytes per Byte stored. Try using a ByteArrayOutputStream or ByteArrayInputStream instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you guessed, all arrays, even ones that contain only primitives, are `Object`s. They are reference types, and it simplifies Java to make every reference type an `Object`.

In a sense, arrays behave identically no matter what type they contain. Being "primitive" is a property of the type, not a property of the container.

Answer (score 2):

Al arrays, including arrays of primitive types, are `Objects`:

```
int intArray[] = new int[5];

if (intArray instanceof Object)
    System.out.println("array is Object");
else System.out.println("array not Object");
```

Output:

```
array is Object
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  `Array`s are `Object`s.

From [§4.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) of the Java Language Specification:

> An object is a class instance or an array.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the case that all arrays, even arrays of primitives, actually extend Object

Yes.